# "Copy snippet to answer" not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

I saw an answer while browsing in Stack Overflow without login. There was a "code snippet" in the answer. I wanted to try the "code snippet" in this answer. But "Copy snippet to answer" option is not available.

Then, I clicked the "Expand snippet" button, then clicked "Return to post". After this process, "Copy snippet to answer" button was revealed. When I clicked this button, nothing happened.

The trouble here is that the "Copy snippet to answer" button doesn't appear at first, or is it "Return to Post"?

Can't I use this feature without login?

For example, you can see the "code snippet" in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814).

Note: Why such a request? - My login information is being deleted continuously because I have cleared cache continuously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You in fact *can* use this feature without logging in through the way you described (first expanding the snippet, then clicking back to post).

However, you *can't* draft answers on protected questions (such as the one you linked) without being logged in as a user with more than 10 reputation. This is by design, since we don't want users to write answers on questions and then be unable to post them because they lack the required reputation. This means that on protected questions, you do have to log in first to use the feature.

Comment: My main purpose is to test the "snippet" by editing without login. I can only run the "snippet" without login. I can't make changes.

Comment: As said, you need to log in if you want to write an answer on a protected question. Doesn't make a difference what your intention behind it is.

Comment: I am sorry for my English. I may not have told my problem. I do not want to answer the question. I just want to test it by editing the "snippet".

Comment: Eh... I'm going to repeat myself once again: you can't write an answer on a protected question. _Copy snippet to answer_ copies the snippet to a new answer, which it can't do if you can't write an answer. It doesn't make a difference that you don't intend to write an answer, it won't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The only way to fix that "snippet" is to write the answer, I guess it's impossible to say it's impossible.